# Lua - simple iterator assignment?

Tags: iterator, lua

I'm new to Lua so please bear with this simple question :)

I'm simply trying to iterate over a table, and modify it's values. however, it seems I can't modify directly the "value" part?

code:

```
for id,value in pairs(some_table) do
    value = value * some_math_here
end
```

will i actually need to modify some_table[id] instead, or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will actually need to modify

```
some_table[id]
```

instead. value does not actually represent some_table[id]

Comment: thanks. i considered other methods (since im loading the tables i could use "closure" functions, but it seems this is the simplest.

Comment: no problem , seems you had answered your own question, but glad I could verify. :)